# How to highlight borders with D3 and Topojson

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I have loaded a map using D3 and it's extension [Topojson](http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js). For this I used a SHP file that I converted to GeoJSON using ogr2ogr and then converted again to TopoJSON also with ogr2org. The method I used is described in the [Let's Make a Map](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) page from D3 creator.

I display a country with it's subdivision ([French department](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Departments_of_France)). When the cursor hovers over a department, I want the borders of that department to be red.

So I add my department like so:

```
svg.selectAll("path")
   .data(subunits.features)
   .enter()
     .append("path")
     .attr("d", path)
     .attr("class", "departement");
```

And, in the CSS,

```
path.departement { 
  stroke: #FFF;
}

path.departement:hover { 
  pointer-events:all; /* Necessary to catch hover */
  stroke: #F00;
}
```

My problem is when doing this, only part of the borders are red. Seems like the topojson format is only implementing the minimum path to recreate your geometry. So when you hover a place that is surrounded by other places, only some borders are part of the path and will turn red.

[image]

The only solution I see is using the topojson.mesh like shown in the article aforementioned. But that looks overkill. I would have to redraw all the mesh and then add the ID of each department as class. Then I would have to create a CSS rule for each department... There must be a better way.

Comment: please check first may be in this case path is closed but the another path is on top of other and not shown

Comment: Have you tried using GeoJSON instead?

Comment: Lars, my file in GeoJSON: 1.6M, in TopoJson: 172K... Amit, bear with me while I check your hypothesis. For this I guess I should change the zindex dynamically when the path is hovered.